# Are there Linux system APIs that can be used to track context switches?

Tags: linux

I am interested in writing a performance profiler (just for fun). I would like to track context switches in Linux so that I can record the time between context-switch-in and context-switch-out of threads (belonging to the process being profiled). I would also like to record the associated callstack (in cases when they're different from previously recorded stacks) besides time.

Also, I am wondering if there is something similar to Windows' ETW on Linux?

PS: I did try searching online, but could not find any relevant info. The approach seems to be to use timer based signals, but I feel that would be imprecise.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTrace (it is available on many Linux distributions). It can among other things, instrument context switches so you can get that information.

It is the most similar to ETW on *nix.

Also linux_perf may already do what you want to -- https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page

You were not very clear on what you really wanted, so hopefully these pointers help.

Comment: Sorry that you did not find my question clear. I want to get a callback every time threads of the process of interest are involved in a context switch. This way, I would like to record time spent executing on the CPU, callstacks and maybe other details. Basically, I want to read (from the profiler that I am writing) relevant data (such as time, callstacks, IP etc) only when threads of interest are context switched in. Otherwise, I would have to sample based on a timer. Please let me know if I am still not clear. I will check out the links that you mention.